# How to make a custom script tag for Html in Cake Php

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I'm trying to import a js file as type module in CakePHP 2.10.22. You can do something like this

```
echo $this->Html->script('test', array('inline' => false, 'type' => 'module'));
```

but that results in the tag being like `<script type="text/javascript" type="module">`

I also tired

```
echo $this->Html->tag(
    'script',
    null,
    array(
        'type' => 'module',
        'src' => '/test/js/objects/test.js'
    )
);
```

But it does not put it inside of the head html tag.

Is there a way to add on or make a custom helper that will add it into the head?

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`), there is no `inline` option anymore ever since CakePHP 3.0

Comment: @ndm I'm on 2.10.22! Sorry for not adding that in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the HTML helper, one option would be to customize the template that is used for generating the script tag, that is `javascriptlink`, which by default [**has the `type` attribute hard coded**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.10.22/lib/Cake/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php#L105):

```php
// in app/Config/html_tags.php
$config = array(
    'tags' => array(
        'javascriptlink' => '<script src="%s"%s></script>',
        // ...
    ),
);
```

```php
// in your view layout or template
$this->Html->loadConfig('html_tags');

// or in your (App)Controller
public $helpers = array(
    'Html' => array(
        'configFile' => 'html_tags',
    ),
);
```

This would then require that you always specify a `type` for your script tags in case needed.

Another option would be to generate custom tags as shown in your question, and use the view's `append()` method to add it to the respective view block that renders in your layout, by default that would be the block named `script`:

```php
$scriptTag = $this->Html->tag(/* ... */);
$this->append('script', $scriptTag);
```

This could certainly be implemented in a custom/extended HTML helper if you wanted to.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > HtmlHelper > Changing the tags output by HtmlHelper](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#changing-the-tags-output-by-htmlhelper)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Using view blocks](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/views.html#using-view-blocks)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Creating Helpers](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Using and Configuring Helpers](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/views/helpers.html#using-and-configuring-helpers)**